# Is there a way to get the id's of a Set<Entity> in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

I have an `Entity` class which contains `Set<Another Entity>` mapped to it, and I am saving it . Now i can get the id of the Entity by `entity.getId()` , but I need to get the id's of the `set<anotherEntity>`.
Is there a way to get them directly after saving?

Answer (score 0):

What about `List<Long> allIds = set.stream().mapToLong(e -> e.getId())`?